# How do I remove ATI video drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have a Radeon HD4850 video card and two monitors. When I try to activate the drivers from the "Additional Drivers" app, it either fails or it will not let me use two monitors.

I downloaded the drivers from the website and once I run, it says that I have to delete previous versions before, or I can use "force" which is not recommended.

Questions:

How would I go about uninstalling the drivers if they are not activated?

If it fails at any point how would I revert back?