# AAKKK! 12.10 Messed my display up! Help

Tags: 12.10, drivers, video

Okay so I had a pretty good set up going. 
I have a great machine, decided to take plunge and run Linux as my primary OS.
Totally loving it BTW wish I had made the switch years ago.

So I installed Ubuntu, everything was great.

I have a 3 monitor set up with a brand new ATI FirePro V7900

When I installed Ubuntu, it picked everything right up no problem, displays were beautiful.

I noticed just a little of lag and some very slight pixelation or artifacting so I decided to install the drivers to see if it would give me an edge. In hindsight, I should have never done it.

I downloaded the ATI/AMD Linux drivers for the card, installed the Linux headers, rebooted, and bam, lost everything.

No multiple monitors, super low resolution, and my launcher is nowhere to be found.

I'm stuck.

The drivers made a backup of Xorg.conf. I restored it, nothing.

For what it's worth, I wanted to try gnome-panel so I installed it just before I did the drivers. I noticed it was a little shaky so I don't know what can be attributed to that and what issues are related to the driver install.

First the launcher went, then the resolution and multiple displays on a subsequent reboot.

Found something online about downloading compiz manager to get the launcher back. Think that made everything worse. I did too much at once, now I don't know what caused what or even where to begin with fixing it.

Ahhh! It was so sweet while it lasted.

Now I'm busted, can't figure out what to do.

Comment: Did you follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ATI drivers - [How do I remove ATI video drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174478/how-do-i-remove-ati-video-drivers) .

If it doesn't work , then Try this easy method - Reinstall Ubuntu. Definitely not a good solution but a quicker one.It hardly take few mins :)